# fitnesse how to write a fixture to take values from rows as supposed to columns

Tags: java, fitnesse

Requirement is like

|setParam0|abc|

|setParam1|p1|

|setParam2|p2|

once all these parameters are set, i need to calculate a signature say sign() whose return value along with these parameters i need to use it in the next fixture

The reason for row than column is the param values are long strings

Comment: Please include your code, even it is not working.  SO can help with errors but isn't a code writing server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using a [Slim script table](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable), maybe in combination with a [Symbol](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables)? That should be able to do this for you.

You'd get something like:

```
|script|your fixture|
|setParam0|abc|
|setParam1|asdasdd|
|$sig=|sign|
```

Where you could use the return value as `$sig` in the next fixture.